# Count number of rows with blank cells (Excel / VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, cell

Hi i'm trying to count the number of rows which contain blank cells. (I know there are 963 blank cells, i just don't know how many rows they're spread across)

I've very limited knowledge of VBA and am finding it difficult to implement.

The way i'm thinking...

Two for loops.

Outer loop will cycle down the rows

Inner loop will cycle across each cell in the row

When a blank cell is encountered in a row a counter will increment by one and we'll move to the next row.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fairly easy way to do it without VBA:

[image: Example1]

Comment: +1 For a NonVBA Solution :) You might want to change it so that it shows the total number of blanks in Col E instead of `1`?

Comment: the image you linked to is broken. this is why it's best to not do this.

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't need any loops to do this.

This sample checks row A. Change "Const column_to_test" number to the column number you wish to check for blank cells.

```
  Sub countblank()
   'This will count the number of rows that have a blank cell in column "A"
    Const column_to_test = 1    'first column (A)
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, column_to_test), Cells(Rows.Count, column_to_test).End(xlUp))
    MsgBox ("There are " & r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count & " Rows with blank cells")

    'You may want to select those rows (for deletion?)

     r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Select 'change .Select to .Delete

 End Sub
```

Comment: @Siddharth Rout **That** doesn't happen often.

Comment: :) I had to delete my post because of that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Sub countBlankInRow()

    Dim counter As Long
    For i = 1 To 1000  ' specify your rows
        For j = 1 To 26 ' specify your columns

            If Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
                Exit For
            Else
                If j = 26 Then counter = counter + 1 ' Alter the col no accordingly
            End If
        Next
    Next


    MsgBox counter
End Sub
```